# How do I compute row percentages in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the percentage of the week for each column.

Week 5 has the following result:

```
Week    1  2 a 4   5  6 a 9  10  10+
3       2      2   1      0   0    0
4      44     68  18     33   4   27
5     198    313  70    142  20  259
```

I expect to see the percentages for each group for all dataframe rows.

```
Week    1  2 a 4   5  6 a 9  10  10+
5.    20%    31%  7%    14%  2%  26%
```

Comment: Can you break down the computation of 20% for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Week as index, you can do this:

```
(df.T/df.sum(axis=1)).T*100
```

```
       1      2 a 4          5      6 a 9        10        10+
Week                                                                 
3     40.000000  40.000000  20.000000   0.000000  0.000000   0.000000
4     22.680412  35.051546   9.278351  17.010309  2.061856  13.917526
5     19.760479  31.237525   6.986028  14.171657  1.996008  25.848303
```

Comment: I don't see the point of doing a double transposition when pandas' `div` has an `axis` parameter…

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you might want:

```
tmp = df.set_index('Week')

out = tmp.div(tmp.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100).round().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Week     1  2 a 4     5  6 a 9   10   10+
0     3  40.0   40.0  20.0    0.0  0.0   0.0
1     4  23.0   35.0   9.0   17.0  2.0  14.0
2     5  20.0   31.0   7.0   14.0  2.0  26.0
```